# Bind Jquery on Scroll

Tags: jquery, mouse, bind

I want Bind this code when users scroll down on region not when web site load?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myStathalf').circliful();
    $('#myStat').circliful();
    $('#myStathalf2').circliful();
    $('#myStat2').circliful();
});
```

Comment: $("body").scroll(function({...}));

Comment: hi I want do this like bottom circles  load on mousewheel

http://www.bitpublimedia.ro/themeforest/resume-v2/index-4.html

Answer (score 0):

You should bind an event on window or body, or anything contains your scrollable content, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(window).on( "scroll", function(){
        alert("Scrolling");
        $('#myStathalf').circliful();
        $('#myStat').circliful();
        $('#myStathalf2').circliful();
        $('#myStat2').circliful();

    });
});
```

demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/4TSMr/

Comment: hi I want do this like bottom circles  load on mousewheel

http://www.bitpublimedia.ro/themeforest/resume-v2/index-4.html